# looking for a function that count the frequency and select the best combinations of words of a tweet

Tags: python, nltk, python-itertools, sentiment-analysis

I created this function which produces every combination of two words within the tweet including the bigrams. for example, this tweet:
"Facebook and Alibaba are reporting mind-blowing increases in mobile usage"

will be tokenized to:

[’ Facebook Alibaba',’ Facebook reporting’,’ Facebook mind-blowing’,’ Facebook increases’,’ Facebook mobile’,’ Facebook usage’,’
Alibaba reporting’,’ Alibaba mind-blowing ’,’ Alibaba increases’,’ Alibaba mobile’,’ Alibaba usage’,’ reporting mind-blowing’,’ reporting increases’,’ reporting mobile’,’ reporting usage’,’ mind-blowing increases’,’ mind-blowing mobile’,’ mind-blowing usage’,’ increases mobile’,’ increases usage’,’ mobile usage’]

The function is:

```
   def mulibigramReturner (str_tweet_text,stopWords):


         multibigramFeatureVector = []
        list_str_words =getTokens( str_tweet_text,stopWords)

        for item in itertools.combinations(list_str_words, 2):
            multibigramFeatureVector.append(' '.join([item[0], item[1]]))
   return multibigramFeatureVector
```

the problem is to count the frequency  find a function in NLTK like BigramCollocationFinder and BigramAssocMeasures to count the frequency and find the best combinations as features for later classification proccess. could you give me a hint to overcome this  problem.

Comment: your code has weird indentation. Also it's not clear what you want? Is something wrong with your function? Something missing in the return? Please have a look at [mcve]. :)